# Using Excel for Billing and Site down calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would really appreciate some help with excel Time calculation. 
I have been trying to create a report that would calculate the effected time based on when the downtime starts and when the downtime ends.

so if an employee clocks in at 12:00pm and at 4:00 pm clocks out for lunch and then clocks back in after an hour but the site went down 30min before he clocked out at 3:30 pm and was back up at 7:00 pm, so want to know for billing purposes how much time was he clocked in during the time the site was down.

1) Are you talking about a 1-shift, 2-shift or 3-shift workplace?

Ans (1) Yes, its a 24/7 operation

2) Is any shift extending over midnight?

Ans (2) Yes. 24/7 operation.

3) Do the time entries hold the date also (even though display might be defined as time only)

Ans(3) No dates. only based on 24 hrs.

4) Can a downtime start at any time and last for any time (even > 24h)?

Ans (4) Good Question. Can a downtime start at any time? Yes. and last for any time? Yes. but as of now it hasten exceed 24 hrs. and the max it has been is 19 hrs.

5) Is a User Defined Function (UDF) permitted (requires loosened security settings)

Ans (5) maybe not but i am not really sure on this one. Sorry.

(1) Just to be clear beyond doubt, are you saying that Columns C-I in your illustration are inputs (values entered by a user) and Column J is the result that you want Excel to compute?

Ans (1)Columns C to G are Inputs that is from the Roster. Column H & I are manually enterd and yes Column J is the result.

(2) Can you clarify the overall structure of the worksheet?

Ans (2) The Worksheet is an Employee Roster. we manually add Downtime start and end.

(2a) You show only one employee. Do you have other employees? Are they listed on subsequent rows?

Ans (2a) Yes its a 24hrs operation so multiple employees and listed per rows.

(2b) Is the site down once every day (or once every shift)? If the site stays up all day, what goes into Columns H and I?

Ans (2b) Site is usually down 1 a week. if the site is not down we dont need to run the report.

(2c) If the site goes down twice during a shift (i.e., it goes down, comes back up, goes down again, and comes back up again), where are the times stored?
 
Ans (2c) Good Question, it hasten happened as of yet so did not consider it but definitely a big possibility. as the site goes down we raise an IT ticket and log the time till its back up and running then close the ticket and log the time.

(2d) Assuming that you have multiple employees (listed on separate rows), is the site down time duplicated on every row?

Ans( 2d) Yes. cause we need to find out how many employees were impacted and how many hrs they were not able to work.

We have three shifts Morning , Evening , OverNight.

Morning Starts from 6:00 am , 7:00 am & 8:00 am

Evening Starts from 3:00 pm, 4:00 pm & 5:00 pm

OverNight Starts from 8:00 pm, 9:00 PM, & 10:00 PM

All team work 9 hrs shift minus the 1 hr lunch.

[image]

P.s : for some reason i am not receiving alerts on my email for this thread. so thought no one responded.

Update:
As per the second screenshot of the sample image the formula does not seem to work for a 24/7 operation. any reason why?

[image]

Comment: I must ask you to clarify a few points, and please **answer by editing your question** and not here in comments. 
1) Are you talking about a 1-shift, 2-shift or 3-shift workplace?
2) Is any shift extending over midnight?
3) Do the time entries hold the date also (even though display might be defined as time only)
4) Can a downtime start at any time and last for any time (even > 24h)?
5) Is a User Defined Function (UDF) permitted (requires loosened security settings)

Comment: (1) Just to be clear beyond doubt, are you saying that Columns `C`-`I` in your illustration are inputs (values entered by a user) and Column `J` is the result that you want Excel to compute? (2) Can you clarify the overall structure of the worksheet? (2a) You show only one employee. Do you have other employees? Are they listed on subsequent rows? (2b) Is the site down once every day (or once every shift)? If the site stays up all day, what goes into Columns `H` and `I`?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2c) If the site goes down twice during a shift (i.e., it goes down, comes back up, goes down again, and comes back up again), where are the times stored?  (2d) Assuming that you have multiple employees (listed on separate rows), is the site down time duplicated on every row? … … … … … … … … … … … As Tom Brunberg said, please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not yet answered my request for additional info, so my answer considers no workshifts over midnight, only time periods 00:00 to 23:59:59 and also only one down time per day.

Think of a workday as two periods (before and after lunch) that you evaluate exactly in the same way. The periods are `ClockIn` to `LunchOut` and `LunchIn` to `ClockOut`. You then add the results of these periods for the final answer.

For each period there might be following events:

```
            In                          Out
WorkTime    +----------------------------+

DownTime  - +-------E                           DT started before WT, ended during WT

DownTime  - +----------------------------+- - - DT started before WT, ended after WT

DownTime           +--------------+             DT started during WT, ended during WT

DownTime           +---------------------+- - - DT started during WT, ended after WT
```

Marking `DownTimeStart` with `DTS` and `DownTimeEnd` with `DTE` and
marking `WorkTimeStart` with `WTS` and `WorkTimeEnd` with `WTE` and 
marking the overlapping time with `OL`, we get following formula for **one period**

```
OL = MAX(MIN(WTE, DTE) - MAX(WTS, DTS),0)
```

The outermost `MAX` is to prevent negative values

And when we add `OL` before and after lunch:

```
=MAX(MIN(G11,I11)-MAX(F11,H11),0) + MAX(MIN(E11,I11)-MAX(D11,H11),0)
```

Comment: Hey Tom,
would this work for a 24/7 operation ? i have uploaded a screenshot of the sample it does not seem to be working for me. could you help what could be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Hassan, as I said at the top, over midnight times are not considered. To deal with those (without actual dates in the entries) you could do: 1) for worktime entries (as work time is defined as 9 hours) add columns to check whether a time is smaller than the time in the previous column and if so, add 1 (for 24 hours) to the entry value. Then use these new columns for the formula I presented earlier. For the down time entries however, such logic doesn't work. There is now way to know if a `DTStart` or `DTEnd` time (without dates) refers to e.g. before `clockIn` or after `lunchIn`.